# Grant Select on Table

Tags: oracle, select, sql-grant

I am trying to set up User_2 in Oracle, and have that user be granted SELECT on a table by User_1.  No matter what I do, create a role and grant select to the role, or grant the User_2 the `SELECT` directly, all I get is 'Table or View does not exist'.  However, if I qualify the table name with the DB Owner, I get my select.

Example, User_1.Items is granted SELECT to User_2.  If I then query `SELECT * FROM ITEMS`, I get the error.

However, if I try `SELECT * FROM USER_1.ITEMS`, I get it fine.  Is that the way it has to be?  I thought the User_1 prefix was implied by the grant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it must be that way.  Suppose `USER_3` also did `GRANT SELECT ON USER3.ITEMS TO USER_2`.  Whose `ITEMS` table would you expect `USER_2` to see if he could just run `SELECT * FROM ITEMS`?  It would be ambiguous.

To prevent such ambiguity, when `USER_2` does a `SELECT ... FROM TABLE`, Oracle used the table is `USER_2`'s namespace.

If you want `ITEMS` in the `USER_2` namespace to point to `USER_1.ITEMS`, you need a synonym, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM USER_2.ITEMS FOR USER_1.ITEMS;
```

Now, `USER_2` can run

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS
```

And it will return the data from the `USER_1.ITEMS` table.

P.S.  If you want to give someone read-only access to a table, you should grant the `READ` privilege instead of the `SELECT` privilege.  The `SELECT` privilege include the ability to `SELECT..FOR UPDATE`, creating locks on your data, potentially disrupting the users who are authorized to write to the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't qualify the table name (when logged in as USER_2), the only tables you (an idealized "you" here!) can access are those in the USER_2 schema, or tables for which someone created a synonym.

This is as it should be. The grant allows USER_2 to access the table, but it does not create a **synonym** (see the concept in the documentation). Think about this: USER_4 and USER_5 may both have tables (in their own schemas) named TBL; they can both grant access to USER_2. So then, when USER_2 references "TBL" without qualification, which table is really meant?